# HTML, multiple select box, disable on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have a multiple `select` box in html. I am using the jQuery `chosen` plugin to make the select box more user friendly. I was hoping that I could implement the following function, but I had no idea how to do it. Forgive me, I am very new to HTML.

I want the box to not allow any other input (i.e. become single select) when the user selects "Any" from the options list.

Similarly, when the user inputs any other option except "Any", I want "Any" to be disabled.

So for example I have a multiple `select` box with the following options:

- Any
- Germany
- France
- USA
- Saudi Arabia

So basically the user can either select some combination of Germany, France, USA, and Saudi Arabia, but not with the "Any" option, or they can choose "Any" and nothing else.

Comment: You could deselect all other selected items if "Any" has been selected. And the other way around you could deselect "Any" if one of the countries has been selected.

Comment: Could you provide some code ?

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
  <select id='country'>
    <option> </option>
    <option id='any' value='any'>Any</option>
    <option id='germany' value='germany'>Germany</option>
    <option id='france' value='france'>France</option>
    <option id='usa' value='usa'>USA</option>
</select>



  $( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#country").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'any') {
        $('#germany').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#france').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $('#usa').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        currentSelect = -1;
    } else {
       $('#any').attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-

```
var any = false;
$("select").change(function(){
    var str = $("select").val();
    var n = str.toString().search("Any,");
    if(n==0 && !any){
        $("select option[value!='Any']").each(function(){
            $(this).attr("selected",false);
        });
        any = !any;
        $("select option[value='Any']").attr("selected",true);
    }
    else if(str.toString().search(",")!=-1){
        any = !any;
        $("select option[value='Any']").attr("selected",false);
    }
});
```

make sure you put your value 'Any' for Any label in multiselect

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses the `chosen` plugin:

```js
$('.chosen-select').chosen({});

$('.chosen-select').on('change', function(evt, params) {
    var $s = $(this);
    
    if (params.selected && params.selected == "Any") {
        // disable the select
        $s.children('option').not(':selected').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        });
    }
    else if (params.deselected && params.deselected == "Any") {
        // enable back
        $s.children('option').each(function(){
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        });
    }
    // force chosen update
    $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.4.2/chosen.min.css">
    
<div>
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Any">[Any]</option>
            <option value="United States">United States</option>
            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Aland Islands">Aland Islands</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
            <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>

          </select>    
</div>
```